# Can you add "filters" to the Class View in Visual C++ 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I am using VS 2008 Express. One of the projects I'm working on uses a physics engine. For their own reasons, the maintainers of the engine suggest compiling the source with your project for better stability and compatibility, instead of linking to the static libraries.

This means that in the Class View, all the engine's classes and methods show up together with my own code. It makes it tougher to pick out my own classes from theirs. Can you group the classes with your own custom filters, much in the way you can organize the source files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just right click your project and hit "Add" and then select "New Filter."  It will look like a folder icon, but it will not change the underlying directory structure.

As an aside: Which physics engine are you working with that suggests this?  I can't think of a reason for their suggestion to compile it along with your own project, since static linking should accomplish the same goals.

Comment: Got it. "Add" isn't actually on the Class View's right-click menu, but I found the folder icon button in the top left corner and used that.

Comment: Regarding the physics engine, people have been complaining about runtime errors such as access violations when statically linking with their projects. It might have to do with different VS settings used with making the libraries.

I'm not complaining though: the engine has been used with several high profile games and it works great for my needs.

Comment: But why not compile it from source yourself and statically-link within the project?  I'm still curious as to the *name* of the engine (not that there is a suitable replacement for PAL).

Comment: I will consider compiling them in the future. It's just the static libs provided by them that were buggy. I'm using the Bullet physics engine. Looks like PAL can 'plug into' Bullet as well.

Comment: I've also used PAL with Bullet Physics with static libraries compiled alongside my own project.  Worked great.  You'll save a lot of compilation time (and headaches) if you put it in it's own project (especially if other things rely on the physics library).  I would also recommend looking into Visual Studio "Property Sheets," as they will save you tons of time when working with multiple projects.